# Get Jquery Chosen options display outside the Jquery dialog.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 'Jquery Chosen' in jquery dialog at the bottom. When I open that 'Chosen' the 'Chosen options' are going inside the jquery dialog. Which causes the jquery dialog to get the vertical scroll bar and after closing the 'Chosen' there is empty gap appearing in the dialog.How can I remove the gap after closing the 'Chosen'. Or is there is any way to get the 'Chosen options' out side the dialog.

Comment: Please include code with your questions.

Comment: No it is UI issue. I tried with different styles.

Comment: So somewhere you didn't do it correctly.

Comment: Okay, i'll try some more. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
// Setup my chosen inputs
$('.my-chosen').chosen({});

// Prevent my chosen inputs from getting cut off by jquery ui dialogs
$("body").on("chosen:showing_dropdown", ".my-chosen", function () {
    $(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content").css("overflow","visible");
    $(".ui-dialog").css("overflow","inherit");
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/am7ssqzs/